How is this sentence divided exactly? "ああまでしないと"
特に複数の自殺者の影に彼の影響があったことは、ああまでしないとわからなかった。
The character is speculating a character he knows may be behind a group mass suicide. He recently found out using complicate, supernatural means, so before that, he didn't suspect a thing. Now he's trying to sus him out and thinking how to explain it to people.
"ああまでしないとわからなかった" I'm not sure how to take this here? From context I'd say "without going that far, you can't know", but given the sue of the past version I'm in doubt it's correct

I believe you should read this as "I wouldn't have figured it out if I(?) hadn't gone to such lengths", given the past tense.


ああまでしないとわからなかった。

This わからない is in the past tense. And I think the subject of わかる is the speaker.

❌️ Without going that far, you can't know.
✅️ Without going that far, I couldn't know.
→ If I hadn't gone that far, I couldn't have noticed (that he was behind this).

